# Check to see if record exists before database insert

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a database that contains more than 640,000 records that I update every week with data from a JSON file.  What I want to do is only load records into the database that do not currently exists.  My script below works on small amounts of data but when I try to load a large file it times out (I get a 500 Internal Server Error).  Is there a better way to do this?

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit','2000M');

$url = 'json/OERrecordstest.json';
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$records = json_decode($contents, true);
include("../config.php"); 

echo "<div class='card card-body'>";
foreach($records as $record) {  

    $type = $record['type'];
    $name = $record['title'];
    $title = addslashes($name);
    $creator = $record['author'];
    $author = addslashes($creator);
    $link = addslashes($record['link']);
    $origin = $record['source'];
    $source = addslashes($origin);
    $description = addslashes($record['description']);
    $base_url = $record['base_url'];
    $isbn_number = $record['isbn_number'];
    $e_isbn_number = $record['e_isbn_number'];
    $publication_date = $record['publication_date'];
    $license = $record['license'];
    $subject = addslashes($record['subject']);
    $image_url = $record['image_url'];
    $review = $record['review'];
    $language = $record['language'];
    $license_url = $record['license_url'];
    $publisher = addslashes($record['publisher']);
    $publisher_url = $record['publisher_url'];

    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM oer_search WHERE title=:title AND author=:author AND source=:source");
    $query->bindParam(":title", $name);
    $query->bindParam(":author", $creator);
    $query->bindParam(":source", $origin);
    $query->execute();

    if ($query->rowCount() == 0) {
        $insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO oer_search (type, title, author, link, source, description, base_url, isbn_number, e_isbn_number, publication_date, license, subject, image_url, review, language, license_url, publisher, publisher_url) VALUES ('$type', '$title', '$author', '$link', '$source', '$description', '$base_url', '$isbn_number', '$e_isbn_number', '$publication_date', '$license', '$subject', '$image_url', '$review', '$language', '$license_url', '$publisher', '$publisher_url')");
        $insert->execute();
    }

}

if($insert){
    echo "<p><span class='recordInserted'><em>$name was successfully inserted into SOAR.</em></span></p>";
}
else {
    echo "<p><span class='recordInserted'><em>Record(s) already exist in SOAR.</em></span></p>";
}
echo "</div>";
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I could not comment, I wrote as an answer because my score was not enough. can you change it like this and try it?

```
 $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM oer_search WHERE title=:title AND author=:author AND source=:source limit 1");
```

or

```
<?php
if(!session_id()) session_start();
ini_set('memory_limit', '2000M');

$url = 'json/OERrecordstest.json';
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$records = json_decode($contents, true);
include("../config.php");

echo "<div class='card card-body'>";

if (!$_SESSION["records"]) {
    foreach ($records as $record) {
        $_SESSION["records"][$record["id"]] = $records;
    }
}
$i = 0;
foreach ($_SESSION["records"] as $record) {
    $i++;
    if ($i > 1000) break;

    $type = $record['type'];
    $name = $record['title'];
    $title = addslashes($name);
    $creator = $record['author'];
    $author = addslashes($creator);
    $link = addslashes($record['link']);
    $origin = $record['source'];
    $source = addslashes($origin);
    $description = addslashes($record['description']);
    $base_url = $record['base_url'];
    $isbn_number = $record['isbn_number'];
    $e_isbn_number = $record['e_isbn_number'];
    $publication_date = $record['publication_date'];
    $license = $record['license'];
    $subject = addslashes($record['subject']);
    $image_url = $record['image_url'];
    $review = $record['review'];
    $language = $record['language'];
    $license_url = $record['license_url'];
    $publisher = addslashes($record['publisher']);
    $publisher_url = $record['publisher_url'];

    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM oer_search WHERE title=:title AND author=:author AND source=:source limit 1");
    $query->bindParam(":title", $name);
    $query->bindParam(":author", $creator);
    $query->bindParam(":source", $origin);
    $query->execute();

    if ($query->rowCount() == 0) {
        $insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO oer_search (type, title, author, link, source, description, base_url, isbn_number, e_isbn_number, publication_date, license, subject, image_url, review, language, license_url, publisher, publisher_url) VALUES ('$type', '$title', '$author', '$link', '$source', '$description', '$base_url', '$isbn_number', '$e_isbn_number', '$publication_date', '$license', '$subject', '$image_url', '$review', '$language', '$license_url', '$publisher', '$publisher_url')");
        $insert->execute();

        unset($_SESSION["records"][$record["id"]]);
    }

}

print "remaining data :". count($_SESSION["records"]);
?>
```

Comment: If json is too big, be sure to cut it into pieces

Comment: title, author, source must also index these fields

Comment: If you are doing it temporarily, you can take $ _SESSION $ _SESSION and select 1000 privately by adding 1000 privates and you can do it by removing it from $ _SESSION.

Comment: You can also try increasing the "timeout" time of the server.

Comment: set_time_limit(100); change to

Comment: You can first pull all the data in the database and assign it to an array variable, then check its control in "foreach" from the array variable you assign this, not from the database.

Comment: In general: Avoid SQL queries in Loops

Answer (score -1):

Tipps to speed up mass-imports:

- Move your SQL prepare outside of the loop (you only have to do it once)
- Collect data to insert into batches of 1000 (for example.. usually alot more possible)
- Use transactions / disable Index calculation during insert
- Find duplicates with a lookup array from existing data (don't query the database for each row of your import)
- In general: Avoid SQL queries in Loops

hope that helps a bit